# Short story where diplomats eat babies who failed to meet certain standards

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

What is the name of this short story?

A society is seeking admission to a "federation". At a state dinner it is discovered that the food is actually babies that the society recycles after the babies fail to meet certain standards. The visiting delegation is horrified.

Comment: Do you know when you read this? Was it new at the time? Did you read it in a book or online? If a book do you know what the cover looked like or what any other stories in it were about? If online do you roughly know what site? Can you [edit] in this information?

Comment: There's a similar sub-plot of the BBC Radio 4 comedy "Welcome to our Village, Please Invade Carefully". In which alien invaders have a tradition of eating babies of the races they've conquered, but they don't enjoy it.

Answer (score 48):

Miriam Allen deFord: [**"The Season of the Babies"**](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?97026) (1959).
This is a great short story that challenges our preconceptions of right and wrong.
 The diplomats visiting a lost colony discover at a banquet that they are eating babies; those that didn't make the cut in an annual test of health, intelligence, etc. The hosts, in turn, are aghast that Earth people practice birth control, since this allows sub-par children to flourish at the expense of better children who might otherwise have been born.

Comment: I found a source that backs this up but it only really repeats what you say here, nice job. And congrats on 5k!